# Is it better to store a module's state as a class or a data-attribute?

Tags: performance, dom, accessibility, semantic-web

Consider a simple accordion module that can be expanded or collapsed with user input.

If the state of the module is to be stored on the DOM, which way should this be implemented?

As a class:

```
<article class="accordion-item expanded">...</article>
```

or as a custom data-attribute:

```
<article class="accordion-item" data-state="expanded">...</article>
alternatively...
<article class="accordion-item" data-expanded="true">...</article>
```

With respect to semantics, accessibility and performance, which method should be used and why?

Comment: All three methods are semantically meaningless, i.e. there is no intrinsic semantic value in class names or user-defined custom data attributes and neither will affect the meaning or structure of your markup. Performance is something you have to measure yourself.

Comment: @BoltClock, an argument could be made that storing state in a DOM element's class might not be semantically representative of the point of the class attribute. Additionally, markup can be semantic for developers even if not "semantic" in the strict sense.

Answer (score 1):

For accessibility, you need to do one of two things:

1. Implement an accordion using the WAI-ARIA authoring guidelines for an accordion http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#accordion with the requisite aria-attributes and JavaScript event handlers for keyboard navigation
2. Put the state of the accordion in an off screen text and maintain it whenever it changes. You can do this by adding a `<span>` to each of your articles above and using a technique like the ones described here: http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/hiding-content-for-accessibility